# Article before Multiple adjectives

Tags: adjectives, articles

Which of the following is correct?

> He is a quiet, polite and disciplined boy.

Or

> He is a quiet, polite and a disciplined boy.

Personally, I think the first one is right. But still wanted to be sure.

Comment: As indicated by the answer below, it's not very idiomatic to ***re-introduce*** a repeated / predictable element (***a*** here) if you've already "deleted" it from any preceding items in a list. But this is essentially a matter of stylistic choices, not "unbreakable grammatical rules".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have to be either:

```
"A quiet, a polite, and a disciplined boy."
```

or

```
"A quiet, polite, disciplined boy."
```

Comment: I'm not sure why it would "have" to be written without the optional conjunction if you eliminate the repeated articles.

Comment: @geekahedron, you could write "he is quiet, polite, and a disciplined boy", but to my ear, once you have introduced a list of categories to which the boy belongs, it is not really good form to also either interleave a list of descriptions of the boy himself, or else to use the 'a' inconsistently within the same list.

Comment: I was referring to the conjunction, not the article. The first sentence in the original question ("He is a quiet, polite and disciplined boy") is perfectly fine.

Comment: No, it doesn't *have* to be one of those versions. There is nothing *ungrammatical* about the second version in the question. It's stylistically awkward and unidiomatic, but it's not *wrong*.